# What's 'the catch' with using MaxCDN for Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cdn

So I understand the concept of a CDN (content delivery network) in the sense that that content is delivered in a smart fashion via a distributed network of servers.

I am currently learning bootstrap, and one method for implementing it uses CDNs for the style sheets and javascript. However, I'm trying to figure out what 'the catch' is when I use MaxCDN. Why would a company allow me to use their resources freely like this?

Does MaxCDN rate limit? What's the catch?

Comment: No rate limit. No catch. We built our business on top of Open Source software, this is one of the ways of contributing back to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no catch as such. The companies in question that use a CDN generally want everyone to use their product and have it available quickly and 24/7 without having to maintain their own server parks to handle the loads, so they provide their files using a CDN (that they pay for).

Some folks have an issue with trusting third parties like CDNs for hosting files necessary for the functioning of their site ("what if they're down?") so they provide a local fallback, just in case. [Some howto and backgrounds here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Like the other poster said, there is no catch. CDN providers have access to very cheap bandwidth and providing services like this doesn't really cost them anything.

Here is a good list of free CDNS that you can utilize in your projects: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/free-cdns/